# How to show a label from a third data column on mouseover / hover in a Gnuplot scatter plot?

Tags: mouseover, gnuplot

I have a gnuplot data file:

```
Requested_width,Requested_depth,Requested_word,Name,N,M,Cycle_time,Clk2Q,Area,Total_Area
24,512,24,R1F512X24M8P24,1,1,1.9820,,7446.102,7446
24,512,24,R1F512X24M4P24,1,1,1.9937,,6757.0596,6757
....
```

I want to scatter plot columns 7 and 9 (this I can do!), then I want the name in column 4 to appear when I mouse over a data point. I think it will be too cluttered to have all labels present at all times.

Comment: Related: also click on the point to go to a link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23022545/gnuplot-4-7-hyperlink-hypertext-with-svg-terminal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is completely possible in gnuplot4.7 (the current development branch), but not in previous versions -- The following works just fine when input from an interactive prompt:

```
set term wxt
set termoption enhanced
set datafile sep ','
plot 'test.dat' u 7:9:4 w labels hypertext point pt 7
```

If you put it in a script, you need to invoke gnuplot as `gnuplot -persist script.gp`.

Comment: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_canvas_4.7/hypertext.html shows something like what I want to do

Comment: Thanks very much. Unfortunately it didn't work for me, the terminal was unknown on our setup and the key word hyper text was unknown too :( 
Google charts has come up trumps instead, but thanks for your response

Comment: @user1806063 -- What terminals do you have (and what gnuplot version)?  You can find the version by `print GPVAL_VERSION` (or by just reading the text when you start it up interactively).  Currently the only terminals which will allow this to work according to the docs are `wxt`, `canvas` (which I've never used) and `svg`.  But I'm guessing if the keyword was unrecognized then you're using an older version of gnuplot.  (4.7 hasn't even been released yet)

Comment: We're on 4.0, sorry I didnt think to check that when you talked about 4.7 earlier.

Terminal types:
Available terminal types:
           aed512  AED 512 Terminal
           aed767  AED 767 Terminal
             aifm  Adobe Illustrator 3.0 Format
         bitgraph  BBN Bitgraph Terminal
              cgm  Computer Graphics Metafile
            corel  EPS format for CorelDRAW
             dumb  printer or glass dumb terminal
              dxf  dxf-file for AutoCad (default size 120x80)

Comment: @user1806063 -- 4.0!  That's ancient!  (It's amazing you can get anything done with that :-p)  When I started working with this stuff (7 years ago now?) I think it was at 4.2 ...

Comment: haha, sounds about right for our IT dept. I asked about getting a PERL Graph module added a few weeks ago which spawned a discussion about who should support such things and so far nothings been done.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can I leave you any sort of feed back or anything to boost your profile in anyway?
Gav

Comment: @Gav -- You can upvote (click the little up triangle next to the post), accept (click the little check mark next to the post) or wait and see if anyone gives you a better answer.  If this solution had worked for you, I would recommend you accept it, but since it's a no-go since you don't have a new enough version of gnuplot, It doesn't really matter what you do (I have enough rep).  Who knows, maybe by leaving it open, someone will come up with a clever way to do it with another gnuplot+other freely available tools.  (e.g. post-processing a postscript file or something)

Comment: I don't have enough rep to up vote.
thanks anyway. Google charts seems good enough for what I want, it's a pretty basic data plot, I just want something that users can play with a bit.

Comment: If only it were possible to copy the hypertext / click on links, that would be so awesome :-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23022545/gnuplot-4-7-hyperlink-hypertext-with-svg-terminal I also noted that `with labels` makes graph generation unbearably slow in gnuplot 5.2 for large graphs, I wonder why: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.graphics.apps.gnuplot/qpL8aJIi9ZE

Answer (score 2):

Just use hypertext and specify the correct terminal, you can make hypertext works.

1) You need to use **hypertext** as describe in GNUPlot manual [link](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/gnuplot_cvs.pdf), page 122:

```
set label at 0,0 "Plot origin" hypertext point pt 1
plot 'data' using 1:2:0 with labels hypertext point pt 7 \
title 'mouse over point to see its order in data set'
```

2) There are currently 3 terms that support hypertext: canvas(HTML5), svg, and wxt.
Let's take canvas as an example, on page 182 of the manual, there is an example show you how to use canvas:

```
set term canvas name 'fishplot'
set output 'fishplot.js'
```

And a minimal HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="canvastext.js"></script>
  <script src="gnuplot_common.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="fishplot();">
  <script src="fishplot.js"></script>
  <canvas id="fishplot" width=600 height=400>
    <div id="err_msg">No support for HTML 5 canvas element</div>
  </canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nowadays, the `output` should be an HTML file, as `gnuplot` already produces the required wrapping HTML around the JavaScript core.