# In gnuplot, how to label each point in the plot with its coordinates?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file, abc.dat and I want to plot it with labeling each coordinate like (1,5), (4,6), (2,8) and so on ....

`abc.dat` is like :

```
1  5
4  6
2  8
4  5
7  8
8  9
3  4
```

Comment: You want your labels to be on the x-axis or with the data itself? and what is your plot command?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use the `labels` plotting style for this. That requires three `using` specifiers: x-value, y-value and a string which is placed at the given coordinates. So the easiest command would be:

```
plot 'abc.dat' using 1:2:(sprintf("(%d, %d)", $1, $2)) with labels notitle
```

That places the respective labels centered at the coordinates.

The following command plots a point at the respective coordinate and places the coordinate label a bit shifted near to it:

```
set offset 1,1,1,1
plot 'abc.dat' using 1:2:(sprintf("(%d, %d)", $1, $2)) with labels point  pt 7 offset char 1,1 notitle
```

The result with 4.6.4 is:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to control the font size of those labels?

Comment: @gforce89 Use `font ',14'` or similar: `plot ... with labels point  pt 7 offset char 1,1 font ',14' notitle`, you can also control the alignment with `center` or `right`

Comment: This does not work in epslatex terminal. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: @gforce89 For epslatex you must include the respective macro call in the format: `sprintf("\large (%d, %d)", $1, $2))`.

Comment: This doesnot seem to work. plots as large(x,y) with no reduction in size.

Comment: Sorry, was too early this morning. You must escape the backslash if you have double quotes. Or you use single quotes `sprintf('\large (%d, %d)', $1, $2))`

Comment: Still no luck. Both ways give the same wrong output

Comment: Now I had time to check this: Seems like for this special constellation you must escape the backslash more often: While `set xlabel '\large xlabel'` works fine, you must use `plot ... using 1:2:(sprintf('\\large %d', $2)) w labels`, or `plot ... using 1:2:(sprintf("\\\\large %d, $2)) w labels` in this case here.

Comment: Finally works... but a very strange rule. Does not make sense.

Comment: can we have a second label below the black dot, that is to have the dot labelled above and below it?. The labels can come from a third and a fourth column respectively.