# gnuplot plotting pixel information

Tags: html, plot, gnuplot

I'm trying to plot some data using gnuplot, I also want to map vertical lines within the image to hyperlinks, I made that work by using map and area element in html.

But the thing is the line(rectangle) to which the value is plotted changes with every plot. I can't generalize the positon of points within the plot. Is there anyway to get the plotting pixel information from gnuplot?

Comment: You could use something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44043914/conversion-between-gnuplots-coordinates-systems) to compute the coordinates of your line in the `screen` coordinate system. If you know the dimension of your image then this will allow you to compute the pixel position of that line.

Comment: Alternatively you could use a terminal that produces output in a format that lets users interact with the graph in a web browser, for example the [svg](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_svg_5.2/) or [canvas](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_canvas_5.2/) terminals. This might require some modifications of the javascript code, see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23022545/gnuplot-4-7-hyperlink-hypertext-with-svg-terminal).