# Gnuplot: Show mouseover tooltip containing z value

Tags: gnuplot

I would like the gnuplot terminal to dynamically show something like a tooltip window or label which is showing the z-value of the corresponding plotted cell (either after clicking on it or triggered by mouseover-event). My terminal type is `wxt` and the only thing which seems to be supported by `wxt` is showing the mouse-coordinates in the bottom left hand-corner of the statusbar. An alternative to tooltips could be replacing the shown coordinates in the statusbar with its z-values. In other words: I need some functionality to show dynamically z-values for mouse-positions.

Here is a quick example (on mouseover or -click I would like to see the z-value of the corresponding square):

[image]

And this is the corresponding gnuplot-input:

```
unset key
set cbrange [0:6]
set xrange [0:10]
set yrange [0:5]
set size ratio -1
set cbtics out nomirror
set palette maxcolors 12 model RGB defined (0 '#1a9641', 1 '#a6d96a', 2 '#ffffbf', 3 '#fdae61', 4 '#d7191c')
$map1 << EOD
5.5 4.0 3.5 1.0 0.5 5.0 4.5 3.0 1.5 0.0
2.0 2.5 0.0 5.5 5.5 4.5 3.0 0.5 0.0 1.5
0.5 0.0 0.5 5.5 5.5 0.0 0.5 0.0 1.5 0.0
0.0 0.5 0.0 2.5 3.0 0.5 0.0 0.5 2.0 3.5
0.5 1.0 2.5 4.0 3.5 2.0 2.5 0.0 0.5 1.0
EOD
plot '$map1' using ($1+.5):($2+.5):($3) matrix with image
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269811/how-to-show-a-label-from-a-third-data-column-on-mouseover-hover-in-a-gnuplot-s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plot your data with `plot ... with labels hypertext` to get points with labels that appear when you hover the corresponding point. Because the `hypertext` option works only when a point is plotted, you must first plot the points with hypertext labels, and then the image:

```
unset key
set cbrange [0:6]
set xrange [0:10]
set yrange [0:5]
set size ratio -1
set cbtics out nomirror
set palette maxcolors 12 model RGB defined (0 '#1a9641', 1 '#a6d96a', 2 '#ffffbf', 3 '#fdae61', 4 '#d7191c')
$map1 << EOD
5.5 4.0 3.5 1.0 0.5 5.0 4.5 3.0 1.5 0.0
2.0 2.5 0.0 5.5 5.5 4.5 3.0 0.5 0.0 1.5
0.5 0.0 0.5 5.5 5.5 0.0 0.5 0.0 1.5 0.0
0.0 0.5 0.0 2.5 3.0 0.5 0.0 0.5 2.0 3.5
0.5 1.0 2.5 4.0 3.5 2.0 2.5 0.0 0.5 1.0
EOD
plot '$map1' using ($1+0.5):($2+0.5):(sprintf("%.1f", $3)) matrix with labels hypertext point pointsize 6,\
     '$map1' using ($1+.5):($2+.5):($3) matrix with image
```

Play around with the `pointsize` to change the size of the hover area.

Comment: I like this solution. It is just one additional line and it is possible to use dat-inputfiles as well as datablock variables. But I noticed that `wxt` will slow down extremely in combination with big input matrixes (in my case 180x150). I think plotting all these labels and points for each value of the matrix is too much for the terminal. But for less data this solution seems to be perfect. I wonder if there is another solution which does not slow down the terminal but works as well as yours.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [hypertext labels](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_svg/hypertext.html) for that, but it takes a little bit of work to transform the data from your datablock into individual labels. If you add the following snippet

```
do for [row=1:5] {
   rowdata = $map1[row]
   col = 1
   do for [value in rowdata] {
      set label value at col-0.5,row-0.5 center back  hypertext point pt 4 ps 8
      col = col+1
   }
}
```

to your script right before the `plot` you get what you want:

[image]

It works by placing a square point of roughly the size of a cell in the background of your image, and make each point the anchor for the hypertext that shows its value. Replace `back` with `front` to see and adjust the size of those points.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I wanted. My real data comes from a .dat-file. Is there a way to generate hypertext points from this source, too?